# If array contains text values add them to the database MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, text

So I have an array which usually contains ID numbers (which link up in a database) but if a user adds a new value on the form submission page, the new value is added to the array without an ID number.

This is what I get as an example:

```
Array [tag] => Array ( [28] => 28 [27] => 27 [newtag] => newtag [hellooooo] => hellooooo )
```

I would like to be able to look at the array, if the array contains a text value such as:
`[newtag] => newtag` or `[hellooooo] => hellooooo`

I would like to add the text value to a table.   I know how to use SQL to add to tables but I just need the if statement.  I would then like to change the array values from text to the ID value associated with the value recently added in the database.

So update array so `[newtag] => newtag` becomes `[number] => number` and so on...

I think I can do this by simply getting the last ID added to the table and changing the text variable in the array to this ID..

If you could help in terms of a loop of some kind and the if statement that would be good.

This is in PHP.

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: The programming language is PHP.  I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you can just do

```
foreach( $tag as $key => $val ) {
    if( (is_int($key) == false) && ($key === $val) ) {
       // handle such entry
    }
}
```

but you will fail if user add non text value (like "23").

Comment: I will give this a try tomorrow.  I will use validation methods to prevent the entry of a number :)  What is the `($key === $val)` for?  What's `$val`?

Comment: I tried this and it says `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND` for the code: `foreach( $tag as $key => $val ) { if( (is_int($key) == false)) && ($key === $val) ) { // handle such entry } }`

There was an extra bracket:`if( (is_int($key) == false))`